# How to print text in CPUlator Armv7 DE1-Soc JTAG UART?

Tags: text, printing, uart, armv7, jtag

How can I print some text to the JTAG UART in the ARM simulator "CPUlator Armv7 DE1-Soc"?
Can someone provide a source code sample?

Link to the simulator here: https://cpulator.01xz.net/?sys=arm-de1soc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by using the information provided [here](http://www-ug.eecg.toronto.edu/msl/nios_devices/dev_jtaguart.html).
The code for displaying '0' in the JTAG UART console would then be:

```
.global _start
_start:
        ldr r0,=0xff201000
        mov r1, #'0'
        str r1, [r0]
        b .
```

[image]

I hope this helps.